# Insert a line at specific line number with sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have a script file which I need to modify with another script to insert a text at the 8th line.

String to insert: `Project_Name=sowstest`, into a file called `start`.

I tried to use awk and sed, but my command is getting garbled.

Answer (score 334):

```bash
sed -i '8i This is Line 8' FILE
```

inserts at line 8

```
This is Line 8
```

into file FILE

`-i` does the modification directly to file FILE, no output to stdout, as mentioned in the comments by glenn jackman.

Comment: Yes, the -i switch is specific for GNU-sed.

Comment: This works flawlessly. Thank you. I am wondering what switch shall I use if the same addition of a no is required not as in like an insert but an append? -i inserts at the specific line. How about appending?

Comment: No. -i means "modify the specified file in place". Insert vs. append is achieved with '8isomething' vs. '8asomething', independent from the -i-switch.

Comment: mac users: with homebrew, `brew install gnu-sed` and then use this with `gsed`

Comment: This is super useful! Is there anyway for me to insert spaces at the beginning of the line? I noticed sed is not paying attention to initial whitespace...

Comment: @elju: Yes, mask it with a backslash: `sed '8i\ 8 This is Line 8' FILE`.

Comment: mac users(2): see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42192768/4694621) for a solution using the native `sed`.

Comment: Note that on my GNU `sed` (4.2.2), operating on multiple files will not display to `stdout` as expected, but the `-i` flag will work. (For example: `echo '1\n2\n4' > a; cp a b; sed '3iInsert' a b` will show the change to `a` but not `b`, whereas the `-i` flag *will* make the change to both files.) This was important to me for debugging before `-i`-ing my files.

Comment: @nivk: Well, that wasn't part of the question and this is not the place to answer all possible variations of a question, writing a compendium for sed.

Comment: @userunknown definitely agree. Just thought it might help someone who saw the same thing I did. +1 from me. :)

Comment: I wonder why in the [documentation](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/sed/sed.1.en) they mention only the form with a backslash (`i \ CR text`). I don't see any advantatges over specifying line to be added on the same line.

Comment: There is a problem: it keeps text at line 8! How to NOT keep text at line 8? It seems that I need "replace", not "insert".

Comment: @pmor: Yes, if you don't want to insert, but to replace line 8, you use the substitute command: `echo -e "line "{1..3}"\n" | sed '2s/.*/new 2nd line/'` (used line 2 instead of 8 for brevity).

Comment: Note that **this command does not insert a line if the given/parsed line number is more than the existing line numbers**. For example, if you create an empty file: `touch test.txt` and run `sed -i '1i This is Line 1' test.txt`, it won't insert anything because the file was empty i.e. number of lines=0;

Comment: Note that this command moves the existing text one line below. For example, let's say `test.txt` has `old text` at line number 3, and now, if you run `sed -i '3i new text' test.txt` then the `old text` gets moved to line number 4.

Answer (score 38):

## OS X / macOS / FreeBSD `sed`

The `-i` flag works differently on macOS `sed` than in GNU `sed`.

Here's the way to use it on macOS / OS X:

```
sed -i '' '8i\
8 This is Line 8' FILE
```

See [`man 1 sed`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sed) for more info.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a variable instead of a string literal inline?

Comment: @AndyRay Use double quotes instead. The shell variable will expand then.

Comment: `sed -i '' '8i\
8 This is Line 8\
' FILE` new line break  for macOS

Answer (score 36):

An `ed` answer

```
ed file << END
8i
Project_Name=sowstest
.
w
q
END
```

`.` on its own line ends input mode; `w` writes; `q` quits. GNU ed has a `wq` command to save and quit, but old ed's don't.

Further reading: https://gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html

Answer (score 23):

the awk answer

```bash
awk -v n=8 -v s="Project_Name=sowstest" 'NR == n {print s} {print}' file > file.new
```

Comment: @glenn jackman I need to enter `#define SERVER@"http://10.35.42.54/ms0.8"` to a particular line. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think Nevin just needs to escape the quotes in his string with backslashes

Comment: @waLLe, start with the [awk info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) which has a nice description of how awk works. Here, I have 2 "condition {action}" pairs, the 2nd has no condition which means the action is performed for every record. After you finish reading and you still have questions, let me know.

Comment: @glennjackman almost there.. just didn't get this:  file > file.new

Comment: "file" represents the name of the file that awk is working on. `>` is the shell [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) symbol so that awk's output is stored in the file named "file.new".

Comment: @glennjackman. `NR ==n` map the line number, `{print s}` will print the s variable at line 8 . then `{print}` will print all the record in file then you use file.new as redirection.  Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: More or less. I'd say "`NR == n` **tests** the line number". Then, yes, print the variable when the current record number is 8. `{print}` prints every line unconditionally. For more information, click the [tag:awk] tag below the question, then click the "Learn more…" link

Answer (score 18):

POSIX `sed` (and for example OS X's `sed`, the `sed` below) require `i` to be followed by a backslash and a newline. Also at least OS X's `sed` does not include a newline after the inserted text:

```
$ seq 3|gsed '2i1.5'
1
1.5
2
3
$ seq 3|sed '2i1.5'
sed: 1: "2i1.5": command i expects \ followed by text
$ seq 3|sed $'2i\\\n1.5'
1
1.52
3
$ seq 3|sed $'2i\\\n1.5\n'
1
1.5
2
3
```

To replace a line, you can use the `c` (change) or `s` (substitute) commands with a numeric address:

```
$ seq 3|sed $'2c\\\n1.5\n'
1
1.5
3
$ seq 3|gsed '2c1.5'
1
1.5
3
$ seq 3|sed '2s/.*/1.5/'
1
1.5
3
```

Alternatives using `awk`:

```
$ seq 3|awk 'NR==2{print 1.5}1'
1
1.5
2
3
$ seq 3|awk '{print NR==2?1.5:$0}'
1
1.5
3
```

`awk` interprets backslashes in variables passed with `-v` but not in variables passed using `ENVIRON`:

```
$ seq 3|awk -v v='a\ba' '{print NR==2?v:$0}'
1
a
3
$ seq 3|v='a\ba' awk '{print NR==2?ENVIRON["v"]:$0}'
1
a\ba
3
```

Both `ENVIRON` and `-v` are defined by POSIX.

Answer (score 11):

`sed -e '8iProject_Name=sowstest' -i start` using GNU sed

Sample run:

```
[root@node23 ~]# for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do echo "Line #$i"; done > a_file
[root@node23 ~]# cat a_file
Line #1
Line #2
Line #3
Line #4
Line #5
Line #6
Line #7
Line #8
Line #9
Line #10
[root@node23 ~]# sed -e '3ixxx inserted line xxx' -i a_file 
[root@node23 ~]# cat -An a_file 
     1  Line #1$
     2  Line #2$
     3  xxx inserted line xxx$
     4  Line #3$
     5  Line #4$
     6  Line #5$
     7  Line #6$
     8  Line #7$
     9  Line #8$
    10  Line #9$
    11  Line #10$
[root@node23 ~]# 
[root@node23 ~]# sed -e '5ixxx (inserted) "line" xxx' -i a_file
[root@node23 ~]# cat -n a_file 
     1  Line #1
     2  Line #2
     3  xxx inserted line xxx
     4  Line #3
     5  xxx (inserted) "line" xxx
     6  Line #4
     7  Line #5
     8  Line #6
     9  Line #7
    10  Line #8
    11  Line #9
    12  Line #10
[root@node23 ~]#
```

Comment: Where is the trailing `$` coming from on line 3 after the insertion?

Comment: It's from `-A` flag to `cat` :)

Comment: what if the string you want to insert contains quote marks, parentheses etc?

Comment: See update to the text above.

That means, you will have to escape those chars as appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

Perl solutions:

#### quick and dirty:

`perl -lpe 'print "Project_Name=sowstest" if $. == 8' file`

- `-l` strips newlines and adds them back in, eliminating the need for "\n"
- `-p` loops over the input file, printing every line
- `-e` executes the code in single quotes

`$.` is the line number

#### equivalent to @glenn's awk solution, using named arguments:

`perl -slpe 'print $s if $. == $n' -- -n=8 -s="Project_Name=sowstest" file`

- `-s` enables a rudimentary argument parser
- `--` prevents -n and -s from being parsed by the standard perl argument parser

#### positional command arguments:

`perl -lpe 'BEGIN{$n=shift; $s=shift}; print $s if $. == $n' 8 "Project_Name=sowstest" file`

#### environment variables:

```
setenv n 8 ; setenv s "Project_Name=sowstest"
echo $n ; echo $s
perl -slpe 'print $ENV{s} if $. == $ENV{n}' file
```

`ENV` is the hash which contains all environment variables

#### Getopt to parse arguments into hash %o:

`perl -MGetopt::Std -lpe 'BEGIN{getopt("ns",\%o)}; print $o{s} if $. == $o{n}' -- -n 8 -s "Project_Name=sowstest" file`

#### Getopt::Long and longer option names

`perl -MGetopt::Long -lpe 'BEGIN{GetOptions(\%o,"line=i","string=s")}; print $o{string} if $. == $o{line}' -- --line 8 --string "Project_Name=sowstest" file`

Getopt is the recommended standard-library solution.
This may be overkill for one-line perl scripts, but it can be done

Comment: Kudos to you Chris for taking the time to explain all that and lay it out so nicely, but wow this is why I don't like perl.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are on SunOS which is non-GNU, the following code will help:

```
sed '1i\^J
line to add' test.dat > tmp.dat
```

- ^J is inserted with ^V+^J
- Add the newline after '1i.
- \ MUST be the last character of the line.
- The second part of the command must be in a second line.

Answer (score 2):

## macOS `sed` solutions

> for example: inserts at line 1

1. n`s`

```bash
# recommended 
# This command only needs to write one line
$ sed -i '' '1s/^/The new First Line\n/' ./your-source-file-name
```

2. n`i`

```bash
# not recommended 
# This way the command needs to be written on multiple lines
$ sed -i '' '1i\
The new First Line\
' ./your-source-file-name
```

### test demo

```bash
$ sed -i '' '1s/^/Perl  camel\n/' ./multi-line-text.txt
```

[image]

Comment: This recommended solution works nicely in a Makefile!

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed -i "" -e $'4 a\\\n''Project_Name=sowstest' start
```

- This line works fine in macOS

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine in linux to add in 2 lines.

```
sed '2s/$/ myalias/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you umläute

```
sed -i "" -e $'4 a\\\n''Project_Name=sowstest' filename
```

the following was usefull on macOS to be able to add a new line after the 4

In order to loop i created an array of folders, ti iterate on them in mac zsh

```
for foldercc in $foldernames; 

sed -i "" -e $'4 a\\\n''Project_Name=sowstest' $foldercc/filenames;
```