# Add text to file at certain line in Linux

Tags: linux, text-processing

I want to add a specific line, lets say `avatar` to the files that starts with `MakeFile` and `avatar` should be added to the 15th line in the file.

This is how to add text to files:

```
echo 'avatar' >> MakeFile.websvc
```

and this is how to add text to files that starts with MakeFile I think:

```
echo 'avatar' >> *MakeFile.
```

But I can not manage to add this line to the 15th line of the file.

Comment: The second example is wrong. You need to loop through files and add a line to each file individually. If you want to add text in the middle of a file, you need to loop through the file's contents and insert your stuff when you reach the right place.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use `sed` to solve this:

```
sed "15i avatar" Makefile.txt
```

or use the `-i` option to save the changes made to the file.

```
sed -i "15i avatar" Makefile.txt
```

To change all the files beginning that start `Makefile`:

```
sed "15i avatar" Makefile*
```

Note: In the above `15` is your line of interest to place the text.

Comment: what to do if avatar and line number are stored in a variable?

Comment: sed -i "${line_number}i ${text_to_write}" Makefile.txt

Answer (score 4):

Using sed :

```
sed -i '15i\avatar\' Makefile*
```

where the -i option indicates that transformation occurs in-place (which is useful for instance when you want to process several files).

Also, in your question, *MakeFile stands for 'all files that end with MakeFile', while 'all files that begin with MakeFile' would be denoted as MakeFile*.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to pass in the string and the line-number options to the script, try this:

```
perl -i -slpe 'print $s if $. == $n; $. = 0 if eof' -- -n=15 -s="avatar" Makefile*
```

`-i` edit the input file, do not make a backup copy
`$.` is the line number

This is based on my solution to [Insert a line at specific line number with sed or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537490/insert-a-line-at-specific-line-number-with-sed-or-awk/32513340), which contains several other methods of passing options to Perl, as well as explanations of the command line options.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more portable version, you can use `ex`, which will work on *any* *Nix system.  (It's [specified by POSIX.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html))  The Sed commands given so far depend on GNU Sed.

To insert a line containing nothing but "avatar" at the 15th line of each file in the current directory whose name begins with "Makefile.", use:

```
for f in MakeFile.*; do printf '%s\n' 15i 'avatar' . x | ex "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e 'if($.==14){s/\n/\navatar\n/g}if(eof){$.=0}' MakeFile*
```