# How to add a string to line 13 in my text file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, terminal, vi

I have a very large text file that is difficult to open in text editors.

Lines 12 - 15 are:

```
1 15.9994
2 24.305

Atoms
```

I would like to add:

`3 196` to line 14 and then have a blank line between `3 196` and `Atoms` like it is currently. I tried:

```
sed '14 a <3 196>' file.data
```

But it did not seem to change anything. Anyone know of how I can do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Here are your duplicates: [Insert a line at specific line number with sed or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6537490/608639), [Add text to file at certain line in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15157659/608639), [Insert text at specific line number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/271475/56041), [Insert multiple lines of text before specific line using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32007152/608639), etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally, `sed` only writes out the changes. It does not modify the file.

If you want the input file to be modified, you can use GNU sed `-i`:

```
sed -i '14 a <3 196>' file.data
```

Before:

```
[...]
9
10
11
1 15.9994
2 24.305

Atoms
16
17
[...]
```

After:

```
[...]
9
10
11
1 15.9994
2 24.305

<3 196>
Atoms
16
17
[...]
```

Note: If you want it after line 13 instead of 14, change `14` to `13` in your code. Similarly, if you wanted `3 196` instead of `<3 196>`, change `<3 196>` to `3 196` in your code.

Comment: I do not want a blank line between 2 24.304 and 3 196. Is there a way to fix that? I want the blank line after 3 196 and Atoms

Comment: If you want it after line 13 instead of 14, change 14 to 13 in your code.