# Adding a line to multiple files in directory

Tags: linux, command

I have a line to be added to 3rd line of all files in directory. What's the commandline to do this operation
Lets say I want to add "color #c2451 " to 3rd line of files in Class directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and use the `find` cmd piped into `xargs` and the `sed` cmd.
You'd have to `cd` into the directory first with the files.

`find . -type f -name '*' | xargs sed -i "3i color #c2451"`

[Add text to file at certain line in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157659/add-text-to-file-at-certain-line-in-linux)

[Change multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445934/change-multiple-files)