# Bash: insert a line after each line

Tags: regex, awk, sed

So, I have a file called "burpfile". I want to add a specific line "peter" after every second line. An example burpfil can contain:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

I want the bashscript to modify it to become:

```
line1
peter
line2
peter
line3
peter
line4
peter
line5
peter
```

To realise this I have tried sed, since that was the choice in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45964337/11155582

This is what I have got so far. However, since I don't understand sed the script only inserts "peter" at the end of the file. And I don't know why.

```
nr=$(wc -l burpfil | awk '{print $1}')

for i in $(seq 0 2 $nr)
do
   sed -e '$i peter' -i burpfil
done
```

As seen in the codesnippet the command doesn't resemble what is in the thread I linked to. That is because having a variable in the command doesnt work... And I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: Your desired result adds the line after every line, not every other line.

Comment: you say you want to add the line _after_ every second line, but you've got it _before_ the first line too.  Please clarify

Comment: I changed the desired result. Sorry.

Comment: @MrKrisey, your samples were saying that to you want to insert line after each line so I changed your question's subject now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add *before* each line:

```sh
$ echo "line1
line2
line3
line4
line5" | sed 's/^/peter\n/'
peter
line1
peter
line2
peter
line3
peter
line4
peter
line5
```

The sed script is fairly simple.  It's a substitution command `s/regex/replacement/`.  In this case, the regex is just `^`, meaning "beginning of the line".  And the replacement is `peter` plus `\n`, which is a newline special character.
So it reads like this:

> before each line, insert "peter" plus a newline

To add *after* each line:

```sh
$ echo "line1
line2
line3
line4
line5" | sed 's/$/\npeter/'
line1
peter
line2
peter
line3
peter
line4
peter
line5
peter
```

Here, the script is similar except that the regex is `$`, which means "end of the line", and the newline is substituted before `peter` instead of after.  It reads as follows:

> after each line, add a newline and the word "peter"

Comment: That does it. However, I don't understand the sed command completely. Could you explain abit?

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{print $0 ORS "peter"}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** looks like OP changed samples so I changed it as per samples now. Simply printing current line with new line and string value peter then for each line of Input_file.

Answer (score 2):

although there is an accepted answer, for the record the right way to do it in `sed` is not regex substitution, but using the append command

```
$ sed 'a peter' file
```

Comment: No, the "correct" was is to use `i`.  But correctness is in the eye of the beholder. :)

Comment: And (reader beware), not all `sed` accept that syntax.

Comment: `i` will insert text before the line though.  Here it's after.

Comment: Argh....the question was edited!  It used to be inserted before.  Yes, with the edit, `a` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert data before each line (as the question was originally), use `i`:

```
$ yes | nl | sed 4q | sed -e 'i\
peter'
peter
     1  y
peter
     2  y
peter
     3  y
peter
     4  y
```

It's sometimes painful to keep track of which `sed` allow you to skip the literal newline, but if you're using `bash` you can also do: `sed -e $'i\\\npeter'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler awk that uses a custom `ORS` and works without matching any regex:

```
awk -v ORS='\npeter\n' '1' file
```

```
line1
peter
line2
peter
line3
peter
line4
peter
line5
peter
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'p;c peter' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed 'p;s/.*/peter/' file
```

Just for completeness, of course:

```
sed 'a peter' file
```

Is the obvious answer (see karakfa)!