# Sed to Insert a Value after specific line

Tags: shell, sed

Rewriting the whole question Again.

Hi,

I have data in a file (db_config.txt) in below format

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle_client/instantclient_19_11
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ORACLE_HOME"
ORACLE_SID=TESTDB.locahost.com; export ORACLE_SID
export PATH="$ORACLE_HOME:$PATH" 
nohup sqlplus ABCSDC/Pfgrtjf#dtt@TESTDB << EOF
```

Now, I capture the data in a variable

```
 db_connection=`cat db_config.txt`
```

Echo is resulting in correct data.

I am trying to insert this data into another file starting 4th line.

```
sed  "4 i $db_connection" test1.sh
```

I get following error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 98: unknown command: `O'
```

What I understand it is not able to copy $ORACLE_HOME . I tried escaping $  with /$ in the source file but that also didn't help.

Regards.

Comment: Could you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537490/insert-a-line-at-specific-line-number-with-sed-or-awk/6537587 if this helps you.

Comment: If I use that option .. It just replace with db_connection instead of value .. If I do double quote sed I get error .

Comment: `sed  "4 i $db_connection" Input_file` has worked for me fine(removed -i option to avoid inplace save).

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 97: unknown command: `O'  .. I keep getting this error .

Comment: I think some issue with my variable actual content ...

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Please show a representative 5 line file before and after your desired changes. Thank you.

Comment: Have added complete details again.

Comment: It didnt work .. It is not doing  anything

Comment: I am on bash shell ... sed -i '4 r db_config.txt' test1.sh

Comment: Run: `sed -i.bak '4 r db_config.txt' test1.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edited question following `sed` should work:

```sh
sed -i.bak '4 r db_config.txt' test1.sh
```

---

On OSX sed you may use this sed command:

```sh
sed "4 i\\
$db_connection
" test1.sh
```

To save changes inline:

```sh
sed -i.bak "4 i\\
$db_connection
" test1.sh
```